# In C++, how to construct an object referencing to different istream object depending on runtime condition?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, initialization, iostream

I wanna design an object that read from either file or console. If there is a command line argument, this argument is assumed to be a filename and the code will read from the file. Otherwise, the code will read from standard console `cin`. Since both `ifstream` object and `cin` are derived from `istream`, I would like to store in the class a `istream&` reference to either the `ifstream` object or to `cin`. Below is the code of the class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

class Reader {
public:
    Reader(std::istream& is) : is(is) {}
private:
    std::istream& is;
};
```

But I encountered a problem when trying to create such an object according to conditions at run-time. An attempt is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {  //read from file
        std::ifstream in_f(argv[1]);
        if (in_f)
            LineReader reader(in_f);
    }
    else {  //read from console (standard input)
        LineReader reader(std::cin);
    }

    //work on reader ...

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, the `Reader` object is constructed in the conditional statement. It will disappear after the execution goes out. But I need this object to do a lot of work after its construction. So I should define a `Reader` object outside the condition, but I can see no way to initialize it before the condition. I also have no idea how to "assign" a reference to `istream` after initialization because reference can't be changed. Note in addition that `istream` class can't be copied. So could you please teach me how to write the `Reader` class if I wanna store a reference to `istream`, and initialize it according to condition at run-time? My idea is that the code for handling the input, either from console or file, are exactly the same. I wanna reuse a single variable to represent the input stream of different type. Thank you.

PS: I am using C++11, and the code will be run in both Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might simply create a function for `// work on reader`:

```
void do_work(LineReader& reader)
{
    // work on reader
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {  //read from file
        std::ifstream in_f(argv[1]);
        if (in_f) {
            LineReader reader(in_f);
            do_work(reader);
        }
    }
    else {  //read from console (standard input)
        LineReader reader(std::cin);
        do_work(reader);
    }
}
```

or reorganize your code to got reference to `std::istream`:

```
std::istream& get_istream(std::ifstream& in_f, int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {  //read from file
        in_f.open(argv[1]);
    }
    if (in_f) {
        return in_f;
    } else {
        return std::cin;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ifstream in_f;
    LineReader reader(get_istream(in_f, argc, argv));

    // work on reader
}
```

Comment: this will ofc work great, but I think it brings us obvious code duplication

Comment: @bartop: just the function call is similar. (I don't say copy paste whole code in the 2 branches).

Comment: yeh, but adding new type of `istream` to handle will require copy paste

Comment: The two approaches are not equivalent, though, first one does nothing, if file cannot be opened, second one uses `std::cin` as fallback. Both valid, depending on user needs, but maybe worth to highlight?

Comment: @bartop Your going to need different code to check `argv` etc. anyway though? And probably you will start looking at arguments that *don't* do the work (`--help`, `--version`, etc.).

Comment: Just cosmetics: I personally would rather pass the stream as reference to `do_work` and create the line reader only there...